# PDOStatement object and MySQL user defined variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't get this script that uses PDO object and MySQL with user-defined variables to work. I learned that with PDO you can't execute two queries in one call, so I split it to two `query()` calls. But it's still not working. Here is an abstract from my script (connection to MySQL is of course done in a different file, I copied it here so it's all in one place just for the purposes of this question):

```
 $db_hostname = 'localhost';
 $db_username = 'username';
 $db_password = 'pwd';
 $db_name = 'dbname';
 $dsn = "mysql:dbname=$db_name; host=$db_hostname";

 $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
 $strsql = "SET @num := 0, @tp := ''";

 $result=$pdo->query($strsql);

 $strsql = "SELECT " . $offer . "_tp AS tp, " . $offer . "_level AS best_offer, Price
           FROM (
                SELECT " . $offer . "_tp, " . $offer . "_level, Price, 
                    @num := if(@tp = `" . $offer . "_tp`, @num + 1, 1) as level,
                    @tp := `" . $offer . "_tp` as dummy
                FROM tbl_limit_offers
                WHERE Prod_Code = $procCode) as x               
           WHERE x.level = 1";
 $result = $pdo->query($strsql);
 echo $result->rowCount()
```

If I run that query directly in PHPmyAdmin it returns several records. However, running it with PDO object I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

`$result` should be a `PDOStatement` object and `rowCount()` should be one of its methods. So, why is it not working?

Comment: try doing var_dump($result) what does it show.

Comment: Try: `$result->fetchColumn()` does that do the trick for you? (also add `COUNT(*)` in your SQL before you do that)

Comment: @justrohu var_dump($result) shows: boolean false

Comment: it seems like PDOStatement object was never instantiated.

Comment: @user2395238 yes it looks like ... can you do var_dump($pdo)

Comment: @justrohu var_dump($pdo) shows: object(PDO)[1]

Comment: it means you pdo object is properly instantiated ... kindly do the var_dump($strsql) before $result = $pdo->query($strsql); to check if you query built is right

Comment: yeah, i did that already, cut and pasted into PHPmyAdmin, the query worked as expected in PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @justrohu I wonder, on the second line, where I say `$pdo->query($strsql);` Is that correct? Should that be stored in `$result` too? But then, how do I combine the two `$result` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my code. It was the PDO object. When setting it, the dsn cannot have any spaces. After I removed the space in `$dsn` variable, everything worked as expected.
Original `$dsn` variable (not working):

```
 $dsn = "mysql:dbname=$db_name; host=$db_hostname";
```

Correct way (no space after the semicolon):

```
 $dsn = "mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_hostname";
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can do as fellows

```
    $setNumSql = "set @num = ?";
    $stmt = $con->preparedStatement($setNumSql );
    $stmt->executeQuery($num);

    $setTpSql = "set @tp = ?";
    $stmt = $con->preparedStatement($setTpSql);
    $stmt->executeQuery($tp);

    $exampleSql = "select * from tbl where NUM >= @num and TP = @tp";
    $stmt = $con->preparedStatement($exampleSql);
    $stmt->executeQuery();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

- BTW

```
    $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT(:offer_1, "_tp") AS tp, CONCAT(:offer_2, "_level") AS best_offer ...';

    $binds = array();
    $binds['offer_1'] = $offer;
    $binds['offer_2'] = $offer;

    $stmt = $con->preparedStatement($sql);
    $stmt->executeQuery($binds);
```

is better than

```
    $sql = "SELECT " . $offer . "_tp AS tp, " . $offer . "_level AS best_offer ...";
```

Comment: you can't do this without using prepared statement? I am not passing any values in.

Comment: Thanks. Question, is using `CONCAT` the way you indicated better because it looks nicer or because it improves performance of the query?

Comment: So, just to confirm, the only way to use user-defined variables with PDO object is to use prepared statements?

Comment: (2)It just looks nicer for nicer.

Comment: (1) $offer is not the value you pass to the sql statement ?

Comment: (3) I'm also not sure that is the only way, but it works on my system.

Comment: `$offer` is portion of field name and it is dynamically determined by the logic on the fly, it is not based on user's input, and the query is run only once per script, so no real need to prepare the statement. But if it's the only way to do it, I'll do it. I'll wait to see if someone adds more answers, if not I'll accept your answer